# (Pandas) - Agrupar e sumarizar por data

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-3.x, pandas

Olá, sou iniciante no pandas e travei em um problema cujo não achei/entendi como resolver na documentação nem em outros tópicos. Resumidamente preciso agrupar os dias das observações do meu banco de dados em um intervalo de cinco dias, e para cada intervalo calcular a média de ocorrência de acidentes, estou tentando sem sucesso algo como:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5D'))['Acidentes'].mean()
```

> ```
>      Data       Hora    Acidentes    Vítimas ...
> 0  12/02/2017    00          0          0
> 1  12/02/2017    01          2          1
> ...
> 24 13/02/2017    00          1          0
> 25 13/02/2017    01          0          0 
> ...
> 95 30/04/2017    23          3          2
> ```

São ocorrências registradas por dia e por hora, mas a intenção é agrupar por um intervalo de dias e então fazer a média de acidentes para cada intervalo.

Comment: Ajudaria se desses um exemplo (5-10 linhas) do teu dataset, ou algum conteudo da tua fonte (talvez um csv)

Comment: Editei explanando o problema.

Answer (score 3):

Dado esse DataFrame:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd

d = {'Data': ['01/02/2017','06/02/2017','03/02/2017','02/02/2017','01/02/2017'],
     'Acidentes': [0,2,1,0,1],
     'Vitimas': [0,1,0,0,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], format='%d/%m/%Y') #transformei em data
df = df.sort_values(['Data']) #ordenar para vizualizar melhor
>>> print df
   Acidentes       Data  Vitimas
0          0 2017-02-01        0
4          1 2017-02-01        2
3          0 2017-02-02        0
2          1 2017-02-03        0
1          2 2017-02-06        1
```

Podemos usar o [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Data').resample('5D').mean()
>>> print df
            Acidentes  Vitimas
Data                          
2017-02-01        0.5      0.5
2017-02-06        2.0      1.0
```

[Edit]

Voltando as [datas](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__format__) para o padrão original:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['Data'] = df['Data'].apply(lambda x: x.__format__('%d/%m/%Y'))
>>> print df
         Data  Acidentes  Vitimas
0  01/02/2017        0.5      0.5
1  06/02/2017        2.0      1.0
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Esta resposta é perfeita para mim, mas a título de curiosidade, como voltar a data exibida no df para o padrão brasileiro?

Comment: @ViniciusOliveira, mudando o formato dela com o __format__. Editei a resposta com esse adendo.